# Permalink Issue - Funny & Weird

Tags: permalinks

I am having an issue where the permalink for my blog posts shows `www.example.com/blog/_______`. The `/blog` doesn't just seem to go. Please see screenshots.

- [image: http://puu.sh/6Z3fi.png]
- [image]

So then I went here, and changed the structure. But it still reflects `/blog` there.

- [image] (Edit Site)
- [image] (inside the Settings)
- [image] (Permalink Str)

Answer (score 0):

The `/blog/` prefix exists to avoid URL collisions with sub directory sites in a network. See [ticket #12002](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12002).

The most simple solution is to use a sub-domain setup instead.

Or go to `wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=1` and change the permalink there. This doesn’t always work, but mostly it does.

> [image]

Comment: Oh.. I just found out that the /blog has been hard-coded. My posts were having /blog/post-name in its url. After I changed it to /%postname%/ it gave me 404s in the /post-name url. Then I re-installed my WP as I had hardly begun. Removed it from settings first and then from the site permalink menu. Worked. :)